# How to subscribe string data on roslibpy?

Tags: python, ros

SO i want to make a separate print in line 7 but it throws an error:

```
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

This is a working code without line 7,
i am not familiar with lambda, i cant make any return of "message['data']" so that i can print it separately

```
from __future__ import print_function
import roslibpy
client = roslibpy.Ros(host='localhost', port=9090)
client.run()
listener = roslibpy.Topic(client, '/chatter', 'std_msgs/String')
listener.subscribe(lambda message: print('Heard talking: ' + message['data']))
print("ANOTHER PRINT",message['data']) # ERROR
try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    client.terminate()
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO!It is very useful for other people to be able to help you to see the actual error message you get. Can you add it to your post?

Comment: @JacoSolari The error message is actually in the post, but not highlighted and therefore easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

The `subscribe` method of a `Topic` (your `listener`) expects a function as argument (that is executed every time a message is published for that topic). The function used here is an "on-the-fly" `lambda`-function. An equivalent would be:

```
def print_heard_talkling(message):
    print('Heard talking: ' + message['data'])
```

and then

```
listener.subscribe(print_heard_talking)
```

Now you see that `message` is just a placeholder for an argument in a function definition, not an actually accessible variable in your code. And that's exactly what the error message is telling you.