# Storing subscribed topic data in roslibpy to variable

Tags: python, ros

I'm having trouble understanding how to save subscribed topic data (strings) in roslibpy to variables. In former research I've stumbled upon this thread [Roslibpy Subscribe String data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64167864/how-to-subscribe-string-data-on-roslibpy), but I'm still stuck.
Ideally I'd have msg['data'] stored into a variable that I use later on.

All I was able to do so far is print the data that was subscribed for this topic, but I need to forward it. I have also tried returning msg['data'] in my callback function, but that wouldnt work.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import roslibpy

def callback(msg):
    print(msg['data'])


client = roslibpy.Ros(host='localhost', port=9090)
client.run()
listener = roslibpy.Topic(client, '/chatter2', 'std_msgs/String')
listener.subscribe(callback)

try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    client.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is much merit in using roslibpy directly instead normal subscribers. That said, you also cannot return data from a callback; at least in a useful way. This is because callbacks will be running asynchronously and have nowhere to actually return to.

What you're looking for is simply having a global variable that updates every time the callback is called.

```
callback_data = None
def callback(msg):
    global callback_data
    callback_data = msg['data']

def get_lastest_data():
    global callback_data
    print(callback_dadta)
```

As an unrelated point I would also suggest adding a ros `Rate` to your main loop. This will help optimize and reduce CPU load for your node. Issues can also pop up when not allowing ros nodes proper time to sleep.